# Parse a multidensional associative array returned from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im trying to return a specific value from an array returned from a mysql query. Im not sure what it would be called, I'm guessing its a multidimensional associative array, please correct me if im wrong.

My php script

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM flws ORDER BY day LIMIT 1,5";

$query_run = mysql_query($query);

if($query_run){
$flws = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
    $flws[] = $row;
}

var_dump($flws);
//echo $flws[1];

 } else{echo "broken query";}
```

a var dump of $flws returns this:

array(5) { [0]=> array(8) { ["day"]=> string(1) "2" ["openday"]=> string(4) "5.47" ["highday"]=> string(4) "5.54" ["lowday"]=> string(4) "5.41" ["closeday"]=> string(4) "5.48" ["volumeday"]=> string(5) "76700" ["adjday"]=> NULL ["deviationday"]=> NULL } [1]=> array(8) { ["day"]=> string(1) "3" ["openday"]=> string(4) "5.38" ["highday"]=> string(4) "5.47" ["lowday"]=> string(4) "5.29" ["closeday"]=> string(4) "5.44" ["volumeday"]=> string(5) "68000" ["adjday"]=> NULL ["deviationday"]=> NULL } [2]=> array(8) { ["day"]=> string(1) "4" ["openday"]=> string(4) "5.50" ["highday"]=> string(4) "5.50" ["lowday"]=> string(4) "5.36" ["closeday"]=> string(4) "5.39" ["volumeday"]=> string(6) "247500" ["adjday"]=> NULL ["deviationday"]=> NULL } [3]=> array(8) { ["day"]=> string(1) "5" ["openday"]=> string(4) "5.10" ["highday"]=> string(4) "5.46" ["lowday"]=> string(4) "4.99" ["closeday"]=> string(4) "5.44" ["volumeday"]=> string(6) "472300" ["adjday"]=> NULL ["deviationday"]=> NULL } [4]=> array(8) { ["day"]=> string(1) "6" ["openday"]=> string(4) "5.10" ["highday"]=> string(4) "5.15" ["lowday"]=> string(4) "5.00" ["closeday"]=>  string(4) "5.10" ["volumeday"]=> string(6) "115200" ["adjday"]=> NULL ["deviationday"]=>    NULL }

Im not sure how to go about returning a specific value from the resulting array.

Comment: Stop using mysql start using mysqli or pdo

Comment: I'll read the documentation for it after I get this figured out.

Comment: var_dump($flws); what did you get?

Comment: i added it right before you asked ha.

Comment: what you exactly wanted to return?

Comment: Are you using a book or php.net for documentation? 
If you would use php.net you would know that the mysql extension is depricated as of php version 5.5.
(btw, search for multidimensional arrays to sort this out)

Comment: I'm trying to return the "highday" in each row.

Comment: @Lexib0y im using a book, I had no idea it was deprecated. I search for multidimensional associative arrays and didnt find anything.

Comment: I can recommend you to use Php.net in combination with the book.
There are great examples in the comments of each page of the php.net manual which can really give you great extra insight. With Google and Stackoverflow on top, life will be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's multiple `highday` values that you will get. I just print it and you will have all `highday` values as an array in `$arrHighDay`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM flws ORDER BY day LIMIT 1,5";

$query_run = mysql_query($query);

if($query_run){
   $flws = array();

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
      echo $row['highday']; //print value
      $arrHighDay[] = $row['highday']; // assign in an array
   }

print_r($arrHighDay);// you can return this array 

else{
      echo "broken query";
}
```

In your returned page you can get all days like this:

```
foreach($arrHighDay as $a){
   echo $a['highday'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Access array values like this:

```
echo $flws['highday'];
```

It'll echo `highday`'s value.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
    $flws[] = $row['highday'];
}
```

Now array `$flws` contains all column `highday` values.

Comment: I tried that and it says "undefined index". i tried echo $flws["lowday"];